# How to get predicted values from JavaDecsionTreeRegressionExample.java of Spark MLlib?

Tags: java, regression, apache-spark-mllib, decision-tree

I would like to get predicted values from JavaDecisionTreeRegressionExample.java, but not only the description of the decision tree and metrics such as MAE and RMSE. Does anyone know how to do it or which method can I use it to get the predicted values?

I have tried many methods, which are provided by RegressionEvaluator and DecisionTreeRegressionModel classes, to solve this problem, but I still don't know how to get them. So, if anyone knows how to do it, please show me. Thank you very much!

The following is the source code of JavaDecisionTreeRegressionExample.java

```
package org.apache.spark.examples.ml;
// $example on$
import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline;
import org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel;
import org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage;
import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.RegressionEvaluator;
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorIndexer;
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorIndexerModel;
import org.apache.spark.ml.regression.DecisionTreeRegressionModel;
import org.apache.spark.ml.regression.DecisionTreeRegressor;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
// $example off$

public class JavaDecisionTreeRegressionExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("JavaDecisionTreeRegressionExample")
      .getOrCreate();
    // $example on$
    // Load the data stored in LIBSVM format as a DataFrame.
    Dataset<Row> data = spark.read().format("libsvm")
      .load("data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt");

    // Automatically identify categorical features, and index them.
    // Set maxCategories so features with > 4 distinct values are treated as continuous.
    VectorIndexerModel featureIndexer = new VectorIndexer()
      .setInputCol("features")
      .setOutputCol("indexedFeatures")
      .setMaxCategories(4)
      .fit(data);

    // Split the data into training and test sets (30% held out for testing).
    Dataset<Row>[] splits = data.randomSplit(new double[]{0.7, 0.3});
    Dataset<Row> trainingData = splits[0];
    Dataset<Row> testData = splits[1];

    // Train a DecisionTree model.
    DecisionTreeRegressor dt = new DecisionTreeRegressor()
      .setFeaturesCol("indexedFeatures");

    // Chain indexer and tree in a Pipeline.
    Pipeline pipeline = new Pipeline()
      .setStages(new PipelineStage[]{featureIndexer, dt});

    // Train model. This also runs the indexer.
    PipelineModel model = pipeline.fit(trainingData);

    // Make predictions.
    Dataset<Row> predictions = model.transform(testData);

    // Select example rows to display.
    predictions.select("label", "features").show(5);

    // Select (prediction, true label) and compute test error.
    RegressionEvaluator evaluator = new RegressionEvaluator()
      .setLabelCol("label")
      .setPredictionCol("prediction")
      .setMetricName("rmse");
    double rmse = evaluator.evaluate(predictions);
    System.out.println("Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE) on test data = " + rmse);

    DecisionTreeRegressionModel treeModel =
      (DecisionTreeRegressionModel) (model.stages()[1]);
    System.out.println("Learned regression tree model:\n" + treeModel.toDebugString());
    // $example off$

    spark.stop();
  }
}
```

Comment: What does `predictions.select("label", "features").show(5);` display?

Comment: It is only used to display what the format of training data looks like.

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem. `Modify predictions.select("label", "features").show(5);` to `predictions.select("prediction","label", "features").show(5);` Then, you can get predicted values.